# side by side div not aligning when inside a main container div

Tags: css

I can't seem to get my div to align side by side inside a div, can someone see where the problem is?  I am trying to position the divContainer element with a height up to the buttonPanel element and the 2 testDiv elements positioned side by side.  I also tried setting the testDiv element with float: left but that didn't work either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="MSThemeCompatible" content="Yes" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
* {
   font-family: tahoma;
   font-size: 8pt;
}

#buttonPanel {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: buttonface;
}

#buttonPanel hr {
    margin: 0;
}

#buttonPanel button {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 75px;
}

#divContainer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 45px;
    border: 2px solid #FFFF00;  
}

.testDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid blue;     
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="divContainer">
    <div id="test1" class="testDiv">test1</div>
    <div id="test2" class="testDiv">test2</div>
</div>
<div id="buttonPanel">
    <hr/>
    <button id="btnOK">OK</button>
    <button id="btnCancel">Cancel</button>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an example:

you have two div left-div say ldiv and right-div say rdiv.These divs are inside main-div say mdiv
ie

```
<div class = "mdiv">
    <div class="ldiv">
    </div>
    <div class="rdiv">
    </div>
</div>
```

then you css shoul be like this:

```
#mdiv{}
#ldiv {float:left;}
#rdiv{ float:left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes to your code: http://jsfiddle.net/ak9Gs/.  `box-sizing` instructs the browser to take padding and borders into account when sizing an element.

CSS:

```
.testDiv {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid blue;   
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.testDiv:first-of-type {
    float: left;
}

.testDiv:first-of-type {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much DRD. Apart from changing the last css style in your suggestion to .testDiv:last-of-type (to float it right), this solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving width as 50% and border with 2px that's why your div'a were not placed sise by side. If you remove border you can get your div's as you need.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PX4X2/1/)**

**CSS:**

```
.testDiv {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;    
    background-color:#ccc;    
}
.testDiv:first-child{
    display: block;
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;    
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
}
```

I gave color difference instead of border for both test div's.

Answer (score -1):

change the testDiv class to have display of inline then they will be side by side

```
.testDiv {
    display: inline;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid blue;     
}
```

Hope this helps.